# Change line style when passing through node (TikZ)

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is it possible to automatically change line style for a portion of a line, if that portion of a line passes through a node?

I'm trying to recreate this diagram:

[image]

Notice how when the arrows pass through a 'node', the lines turn to dotted lines. This happens for both dashed lines and solid lines. Is it possible to code this in TikZ?

Here is a MWE:

[image]

Additionally, is there any way to prevent the lines from overlapping at the point when they arrive/leave a node? Notice how the three solid lines in the MWE overlap at 'HABITAT'.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width = 0.4mm]

\tikzset{
nodestyle/.style={
  circle,
  inner sep=0pt,
  text width=1.8cm,
  align=center,
%  draw=black,
  }}

% NODES
\node (H) [nodestyle] at (2,0) {HABITAT};
\node (B) [nodestyle] at (8,0) {BIOME};
\node (SU) [nodestyle] at (5,2) {Subsistence};
\node (SH) [nodestyle] at (2.5,3.5) {Shelter/\\Clothing};
\node (TC) [nodestyle] at (7.5,3.5) {Technology};
\node (TP) [nodestyle] at (0,5) {Transport};
\node (TD) [nodestyle] at (10,5) {Trade};
\node (SO) [nodestyle] at (5,6) {Social\\organisation};
\node (LW) [nodestyle] at (2.8,7.5) {Language/\\Writing};
\node (W) [nodestyle] at (7.2,7.5) {War};
\node (A) [nodestyle] at (0,9) {Art};
\node (LM) [nodestyle] at (10,9) {Law/\\Morals};
\node (M) [nodestyle] at (1.75,11.5) {Magic};
\node (SC) [nodestyle] at (8.25,11.5) {Science/\\Cosmology};
\node (R) [nodestyle] at (5,12.5) {Religion};

% ARROWS FROM (H)
\draw [->,dashed] (H)--(TP);
\draw [->,dashed] (H)--(A);
\draw [->,dashed] (H)--(M);
\draw [->,dashed] (H)--(LW);
\draw [->,dashed] (H)--(SH);
\draw [->,dashed] (H)--(R);
\draw [->,dashed] (H)--(SC);
\draw [->,dashed] (H)--(W);
\draw [->,dashed] (H)--(LM);
\draw [<->] (H)--(TC);
\draw [<->] (H)--(SU);
\draw [<->] (H)--(TD);
\draw [<->] (H)--(B);

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Diagram illustrating interrelations of different aspects of culture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not automatically, but you can draw a solid line behind a node and a dashed line on top later.

Comment: I think you can achieve line style change by foreach-loop. In your MWE, you can put all edges outcoming from HABITAT inside a loop and set the line style.

Comment: With all respect that is a horrible visualization of whatever message it is trying to convey.

Comment: @percusse It was a recent candidate for #WorstAcademicDiagrams on Twitter.

Comment: Well, you could certainly do that with intersections and a lot of patience. Just name the lines and the circles of the nodes, fill the nodes white and draw the dotted lines between the intersections afterwards. However, I'd like to argue that filling the nodes with white and some nontrivial opacity will look better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for fun. The boundaries of the nodes are named using `path pictures`, the lines are drawn on the background and if they cross the nodes redrawn dotted in the foreground. And as I said, you need to be patient, the compilation takes a few seconds.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,backgrounds}
\newcounter{mynode}
\setcounter{mynode}{0}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width = 0.4mm]

\tikzset{
nodestyle/.style={
  circle,
  inner sep=0pt,
  text width=1.8cm,
  align=center,
  fill=white,
  path picture={\stepcounter{mynode}
  \path[name path global=node circle \themynode] let \p1=($(path picture bounding box.north)-(path picture bounding
  box.center)$)
  in  (path picture bounding box.center) circle (\y1);
  ;
  },
%  draw=black,
  }}

% NODES
\node (H) [nodestyle] at (2,0) {HABITAT};
\node (B) [nodestyle] at (8,0) {BIOME};
\node (SU) [nodestyle] at (5,2) {Subsistence};
\node (SH) [nodestyle] at (2.5,3.5) {Shelter/\\Clothing};
\node (TC) [nodestyle] at (7.5,3.5) {Technology};
\node (TP) [nodestyle] at (0,5) {Transport};
\node (TD) [nodestyle] at (10,5) {Trade};
\node (SO) [nodestyle] at (5,6) {Social\\organisation};
\node (LW) [nodestyle] at (2.8,7.5) {Language/\\Writing};
\node (W) [nodestyle] at (7.2,7.5) {War};
\node (A) [nodestyle] at (0,9) {Art};
\node (LM) [nodestyle] at (10,9) {Law/\\Morals};
\node (M) [nodestyle] at (1.75,11.5) {Magic};
\node (SC) [nodestyle] at (8.25,11.5) {Science/\\Cosmology};
\node (R) [nodestyle] at (5,12.5) {Religion};

% ARROWS FROM (H)
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\draw [name path global=arr1,->,dashed] (H)--(TP);
\draw [name path global=arr2,->,dashed] (H)--(A);
\draw [name path global=arr3,->,dashed] (H)--(M);
\draw [name path global=arr4,->,dashed] (H)--(LW);
\draw [name path global=arr5,->,dashed] (H)--(SH);
\draw [name path global=arr6,->,dashed] (H)--(R);
\draw [name path global=arr7,->,dashed] (H)--(SC);
\draw [name path global=arr8,->,dashed] (H)--(W);
\draw [name path global=arr9,->,dashed] (H)--(LM);
\draw [name path global=arr10,<->] (H)--(TC);
\draw [name path global=arr11,<->] (H)--(SU);
\draw [name path global=arr12,<->] (H)--(TD);
\draw [name path global=arr13,<->] (H)--(B);
\end{scope}
\foreach \X in {1,...,13}
{
\foreach \Y in {1,...,\themynode}
{
\draw[dotted,name intersections={of={arr\X} and {node circle \Y}, 
    total=\n}] \ifnum\n=2
    (intersection-1) -- (intersection-2)
    \fi;
}
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Diagram illustrating interrelations of different aspects of culture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It is interesting that according to this figure `science` and `cosmology` are separate things. ;-)